QUERY returns parsing error
My query is not working but I can’t find the problem.
=query(Sheet1!A1:AC; "select * WHERE
   H>="&E11&" And I>="&A14&" And J>="&B14&)

It always says that there is a parsing problem, but I can’t find it. I‘d really appreciate any help with finding the mistake.

The problem is the last &.

Just tried yours, but it does not work either

In such case, you should provide more details, like the spreadsheet locale / country, add sample values for the referred ranges and the expected result.

Per @Rubén you have a trailing ampersand operator &
Your formula should be
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:AC; "WHERE H>="& E11 
   &" AND I>="& A14 &" AND J>="& B14)

If you are in North America, the semi-colon ; should also be changed to a comma ,:
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:AC, "WHERE H>="& E11 
   &" AND I>="& A14 &" AND J>="& B14)

